# Error while parsing String value into Double

Tags: selenium-webdriver, string

```
Thread.sleep(1000);
WebElement NetReceivable=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("html/body/form/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[19]/td[2]")));

String NetReceivableamt=NetReceivable.getText();
System.out.println("NetReceivable amount::"+NetReceivableamt); //working fine till here

Double NetReceivableamtint = Double.parseDouble(NetReceivableamt);
                        System.out.println("NetReceivableamtint::"+NetReceivableamtint);
```

** below error getting while parsing it to double**

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "196,003.20"
                            at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
                            at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
                            at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
                            at com.Test.Loan_Termination.Loan_Processing(Loan_Termination.java:431)
                            at com.Test.App.main(App.java:96)
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/4323627/3636601 maybe this helps

Answer (score 5):

Your number is not in the correct double format. Use the [DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) to parse it:

```
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
    DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
    symbols.setDecimalSeparator('.');
    symbols.setGroupingSeparator(',');
    df.setDecimalFormatSymbols(symbols);
    Double NetReceivableamtint = df.parse(NetReceivableamt);
```

Also take care of the Java naming convention. Variable names should start with lower case caracters

Comment: Great answer. I would also add that using `Thread.sleep()` is a very bad practice and it should be avoided